# Search results getting concatenated by a word I put somewhere. How did I manage that and how to revert it?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, database, catalogsearch

This may sound stupid (it really is) but I recently noticed the word "test" is being concatenated to all product names on the catalog search page. I'm almost certain this was my doing (I like to tamper with stuff so I know what they're for), but I have no clue as to what I acutally changed to make this happen, which makes the process of reverting it a pain in the butt.

I tried looking into the files, but the word (like I capitalized it) is not present in the app/design directory. I guess I might have messed with the admin panel settings or the database itself, but don't know where to start looking.

Does anyone have any idea as to where I might want to look?

Comment: Enable the template path hints to see what template is actually used for rendering the search results. If the text is not in that file, you will have at least a place to start debugging.

Comment: also try to search in the whole `app` directory in case insensitive mode. As the text can be uppercased by CSS

Comment: I already did both of those things, thats why I'm inclined to a database/admin panel issue rather than a file per se. The word "Test" doesn't appear in the app/design directory (and sub directories) at all.